# C# & Entity Framework - Is it possible to use if else to switch table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to use if else to switch table name

I try this but it's error

```
var table = null; 

if(1 == 1)
{
    table = db.Table1;
}
else
{
    table = db.Table2;
}

var query = table.ToList();
```

Comment: "I try this but it's error" what error do you get?

Comment: You cannot do var foo = null. You need to provide a strong type (if this is the error you get).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that is possible, but not with `var`. You have to give it a meaningful type:

```
IQueryable<SomeType> table = null;
```

The problem here is: what should go at `SomeType`? Since both types are probably different: both `Table1` and `Table2` return another type. You could let both implement the same interface:

```
IQueryable<ISomeInterface> table = null;
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much